# Why are shotguns banned in a lot of Xbox servers?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have been on a lot of servers recently as I am a new player and I have noticed on most servers there is a shotgun ban.  Is there any particular reason[s] a lot of players tend to ban the use of shotguns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One key reason is many people believe they are completely overpowered in close quarters which eliminates all real skill and encourages a sort of run and gun play style. This is especially a problem in close quarter maps, where it effectively forces everyone to use a shotgun to be in with any real competitive chance. Which just creates a race to get the best shotgun rather than actually using any real skill.

Another reason was due to some of the glitches relating to the M26 I believe.

Comment: yuuuup the amazing M26 Dart

Comment: Is this only on consoles or also on the PC? Haven't played BF3 in a while, would be nice to know.

Comment: @5pike: I haven't seen a single PC server with shotgun ban. I'm guessing the difference is that with pad run&gun is more effective, while on PC opponent using a mouse might easily counter it with accurate head-shots.